# Update SwiftUI list when removing an element in a nested property

Tags: listview, swiftui

So I've got some SwiftUI code that looks like this:

```
struct OverridesListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataStore: DataStore

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(dataStore.data) { element in
                    Text(element.description)
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    self.dataStore.data.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where the `DataStore` struct looks like:

```
struct DataStore {
    var data: [Element]
}
```

It seems when I add a new element to `data` (`dataStore.data.append(newElement)`), the list view gets updated accordingly. However, removing elements from `data` (`self.dataStore.data.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)`), does not seem to update the list. I've set a breakpoint after that line and ensured that `self.dataStore.data` is in fact empty. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this even compiles for you. This is how it works:

```
import SwiftUI

typealias Element = String
class DataStore: ObservableObject {
  @Published var data: [Element]
  init(data: [Element]) {
    self.data = data
  }
}
struct OverridesListView: View {
  @ObservedObject var dataStore: DataStore

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach(dataStore.data, id: \.self) { element in
          Text(element.description)
        }
        .onDelete { indexSet in
          self.dataStore.data.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct OverriesListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    OverridesListView(dataStore: DataStore(data: ["Blah", "Blubb"]))
  }
}
```